# reactivating Segmented Control on click iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

For my app, it currently performs some logic and I also have a `segment control` deselected with:

`[self.tipControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];`

I could leave this as is, but I want to have the option of reenabling this to perform other functions. This is what I have right now

```
if (true) {...
    ...
    ...
    [self.tipControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
}

activate segmented control onclick   //allowing selecting of segments

if (self.segmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex >= 0){
     ... do something...;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where ever you want to enable segment control kindly put code like this :

```
..
..
[self.tipControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0]; // this will enable first segment
..
..
// similarly you can enable other segments with changing index.
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried this but it will set the segmented control to be at 0 and I am not allowed to change between values. I would like to be able to change whenever clicked

Comment: You want your SegmentControl to change the value from one segment to another whenever touched. Then you will be interested in looking [here in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497760/uisegmentedcontrol-calls-action-method-on-changing-selectedsegmentindex-programm) .